# is there any way to allow user to enter only characters and allow whitespace in entry field on keypress in Xamrin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using label to display warning message if User enters other values in entry field except characters and whitespaces

```
<Entry x:Name="txtFirstName" placeholder="Please enter First Name"></Entry>
<label x:Name="warnMessage"/>
```

Comment: You can use regular expression with conditional statements to check for such entry.

Comment: I don't get it, do you want to disable whitespace?

Comment: Or do you want to disable special characters?

Comment: i want to disable special characters but on keypress and the field should only allow characters and whitespaces and the main issue is i am not able to find any keyboard events in xamarin @FreakyAli

Comment: FWIW: "characters" refers to every possible value in a "character set"s range of values. That would not exclude anything. Do you mean "alphabetic characters" and whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe to the Entry's TextChanged event, evaluate the string using a regular expression and then update the label:

```cs
//customize the regex according to your needs
var regex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]*$");

txtFirstName.TextChanged += (s,e) => 
{
    if(!regex.IsMatch(txtFirstName.Text))
    {
        //update error message
    }
}
```

Since I don't know what exactly you want to match against, I recommend checking different versions of the regular expression on https://regexstorm.net

Comment: Some people reading later might prefer to REMOVE (suppress) the incorrect characters. [An alternative interpretation of question's title, though not what this person asks for.] Perhaps add a separate section to answer, to show how to remove the other characters?

Comment: Since it wasn't specified further, my answer stands according to the question. Let's see ;)

Comment: Sure. I upvoted your answer. It is a good answer to question! Originally, I had not carefully read the question, just the title, and interpreted it the way I mention. Then decided others might reach here from google, have the same interpretation.